# Какое расширение в VS Code делает autocomplete кроме Path Autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Мои установленные расширения в VS Code. Много вычитывал каждое, не разобрался.

[image: 2][image: расширения VS Code]

Comment: Ничего не понятно.

Comment: VS Code задваивает автокомплит. К примеру путь к файлу. Папки и файлы задвоены.

Comment: Скриншот покажи.

Comment: добавил скрин к вопросу.

Comment: А что-то я подозреваю, что это сам VS Code умеет без расширений.

Comment: Как вариант... благодарен!